# Twint output list is returning 'NoneType' Error

Tags: python, web-scraping, twitter, twint

I'm writing a simple program to save a given twitter user's tweets word-by-word into a .csv file, as well as using `nltk` to tag them with parts of speech.

When attempting to iterate through `twint.output.tweets_list`, I receive the following error:

`twint.get:User:'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`

I know for a fact that there are tweets to be returned, so it's not simply missing tweets.

My code is as follows:

```
import twint
import csv
import nltk

# Configure Twint object

c = twint.Config()
c.Username = "POTUS"
c.Limit = 100

# Run Twint

twint.run.Search(c)

# Open a CSV file and write the tweets and their parts of speech to it

with open('tweets_with_POS.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(["word", "part_of_speech"])
    for tweet in twint.output.tweets_list:
        words = nltk.word_tokenize(tweet.tweet)
        pos_tags = nltk.pos_tag(words)
        for word, pos in pos_tags:
            writer.writerow([word, pos])
```

I've tried running the code from a variety of networks, thinking it may be an IP block, but it doesn't seem to be. Any help is appreciated.

You will need to include the following code if you want to reproduce this
`nltk.download('punkt') nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger')`

Comment: _"I know for a fact"_ - have you verified the contents of `twint.output`?

Comment: `print(twint.output)` returns the exact same error

Comment: From what I can gather from Twint's Github, the output can only be stored in a .json file. Try outputting it to a .json and opening that.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was with a screwy compatibility issue with Twint.

I ran `pip install --upgrade -e git+https://github.com/twintproject/twint.git@origin/master#egg=twint` to upgrade twint, which had automatically downloaded one version behind the main branch for some reason.

I then encountered `AttributeError: module 'typing' has no attribute '_ClassVar'` which I resolved by running `pip uninstall dataclasses -y`